# How do I compress MySQL ids leaving no gaps

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make MySQL auto-increment id (re) start from 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409718/make-mysql-auto-increment-id-re-start-from-1)

I have a huge 100,000 rows in a MySQL table. How to compress the auto increment rows?

At the moment, its like this

```
id | col1 | col2
------------------
1  | foo  | bar
2  | foo  | foo
4  | bar  | foo
12 | bar  | bar
```

I would like it so the ids will be 1,2,3,4 :

```
id | col1 | col2
------------------
1  | foo  | bar
2  | foo  | foo
4  | bar  | foo
3  | bar  | bar
```